# Jquery popbox conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 buttons and when you click the buttons , a `<div>` will pop up so its like popbox .

I managed to get the first button to pop a `<div>` called bigbox but when I try to click on the second button , It doesn't pop another `<div>` called editbox .

But it works when I deleted the jquery function which controls the first button.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">


        .bigbox  {
            background-color: #F5E49C;
            color: #000;
            padding: 0 5px;
            width:280px;
            text-align: center;content: "";display: none;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }

        .editbox  {
            background-color: #F5E49C;
            color: #000;
            padding: 0 5px;
            width:280px;
            height:500px;
            text-align: center;content: "";
            display: block;
            padding-bottom: 70px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            position: absolute;left:300px;top:1px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="ClickMe">Click Me</button>
    <div id="moveableBox" data-display="hidden" class="bigbox">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="Click">Second pop box</button>
    <div id="ableBox" data-display="hidden" class="editbox">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $("#ClickMe").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                /*if (.attr("data-display") == "visible") {};*/
                $("#moveableBox").fadeToggle();
            });
            $("#moveableBox").draggable({
                handle: "#moveBox"
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to put both of `.click` into one `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`

Comment: @LazKarimov How could I do that?

Comment: put the script stuff at the very end of the <body> tag

Comment: probably it's just for code rearranging. You don't need to separate `.click` functions. Just put them into one `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});` @sinaneker You don't need to put it at the end, because there is `ready` function

Comment: @LazKarimov I meant the <script> tag on the head

Comment: @LazKarimov May You show an example ? Because I tried , I ran out of solutions .

Comment: @sinaneker me too; @JackRoster You should try first to import `jquery-ui` as Christopher Tokar said and try it out.

Comment: @LazKarimov forget about that , I just removed it

Comment: @LazKarimov When you put the script tag, I meant the script tag that load jQuery at the end of the <body> tag it increases the page performance. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is an error showing up in the browser console that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'
```

So you'll have to import jquery-ui as well to get your JS execute to the end, or simply remove the draggable methods.

Secondly, you are calling a toggle function on #ableBox so that disappears because it was visible initially.